# How to guard against scope objects getting changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm an Angular noob. In an app I have taken over there is an object in the scope that defines the role of the current user (e.g. `user.role=REGULAR`).

**Is there a way to keep a user from opening firebug and changing `user.role=ADMIN`?**

For example, I have seen code that shows a tab based on a value in a scope, but I'm not sure how to keep a user from changing that value (and getting access to the tab). Is there a pattern to deal with this? Does everything access-related need to come directly from a web service/protected remote location?

Comment: Don't rely on client-side anything for permissions/access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no way to do this**. Your design has a fundamental issue; it relies on client side validation.

You can **never ever ever ever ever** trust anything coming from the client. Anything that you truly want validated or authenticated must be done on the server side, particularly security related matters.

The most important rule is that once it leaves the server and hits the client, its out of your control. Assume its compromised, assume its not trust-worthy, and assume you have to check everything.

In your case, if a user is not an admin don't even provide them with admin options.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.  Is there a standard way to provide options (tabs, etc) vice hide them and risk a user un-hide them?  I'm thinking something like having totally separate views, but then I would need a view for every combination of roles.  I assume there is a better way?

Comment: The proper way to do that is to either have two completely separate views like you said, or to build the view on the server side such that the browser never sees the disabled features.  You could possibly just hide the admin buttons on the client side, as theoretically it shouldn't matter if the admin buttons are disabled or enabled since you should always validate the user's permissions to do something on the server side.  Again, never trust anything coming from the client.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to hide the object inside of a closure or use `Object.freeze` in browsers that support it, however there is no getting around the fact that the code is being sent to and executed on the client.  Even if there was a foolproof way of preventing modification ( which there isn't ), the client could have modified the payload in Fiddler or something before it reached the browser.

With that in mind, you cannot trust *anything* on the client for access/authorization; you must verify this on the server or you'll have security holes/risks.